# "How we (are) shopping now." Is there a rule to separate Participle and Present Continuous if we use that Adjective with 'ing'?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

For example, in phrase:
"How we're shopping now "

It seems to me that there is a contradiction in grammar construct:

> How we are shopping now.
>   Subject(Noun) + Art(are/is) + Verb(ing) +/- now = Present Continuous

And so, we want to build sentence in the Participle form, but neologism 'Shopping' worked as Noun, Adjective or Verb (by context).

And phrase "How we are shopping now" may be understood literally about our action in current real time.

**Seed of this Question:**

Is it right to throw the art.'are' for build that sentence in
Participle form? And we have semantic difference in there case?
Is it will be right?

> How we shopping now.

Comment: You seem to be asking about rules of grammar in relation to an ungrammatical 4-word sentence (the 5-word version is arguably grammatical, particularly if you add "Oh" to its start). However, it's unclear to me what you're trying to find out.

Comment: As written "How we are shopping now!" can only be a present tense exclamative clause, though it does require an exclamation point. It comprises "how" (adverb); "we" (subject - pronoun); "are shopping now" (predicate - verb phrase comprising progressive aux verb "are" + gerund-participle verb "shopping" + "now" adverb).

Comment: How We Are Shopping Now works as a headline, or perhaps it's a part of a sentence. Shopping is too established even as a gerund to call it a neologism. After a year of saying we Googled things, that word was no longer a neologism. When 'shopping malls' spend money on signs with those words, rest assured they are no neologism.

Comment: Thanks to BillJ,  for the comment that would like to see.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Of course, "neologism" in hooks (quotes).

Comment: @YosefBaskin, yes it must sounds like breaked sentence or headline, like in cinema intros for examples.

Comment: @BillJ And if we use that form as headline: "The Way People (Is?) Shopping Now" - Should we use art. "is" or no for ~Participle form?

Comment: It would be "The Way People Are Shopping Now" with "are shopping" being a present progressive verb phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stand alone your sentence does not parse (Merriam-Webster defines the word parse this way: "to divide (a sentence) into grammatical parts and identify the parts and their relations to each other — parse in a sentence."), 
but I have thought of a couple of ways that it could work:

As a response. For example:

> "What does she want to know? What is she asking you about?"
>   "How we're shopping now."

Although the grammar is imperfect, any native English speaker would understand the response. Wait, let me amend that statement; American's would understand. I can not speak for the British, Australian and etc. English speakers.

With the addition of the word "it's". For example:

> "Were you able to cash your paycheck?"
>   "It's how we're shopping now."

Again, imperfect grammar but it would make sense.

Comment: Can I replace to?
"The Way of People (are?) Shopping Now."